# Flutter Hive - Throwing Overflow Error when copying data from Box to List

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am trying to copy the data from a Box (with a TypeAdapter) to a List. I am getting a Stack Overflow error.

**Code**

```
List<CardFields> starterlist = refilldb("starter");
List<CardFields> tlist = [];
List<CardFields> refilldb(String db) {
  if (db == "starter") {
    starterlist.clear();
    Box starterbox = Hive.box<CardFields>("starter");
    List<CardFields> tlist = starterbox.values.toList() as List<CardFields>;
    return tlist;
  }
```

**Error**

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following StackOverflowError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Stack Overflow

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      starterlist (package:partaykaratay/models/database_mechanics.dart:66:18)
#1      starterlist (package:partaykaratay/models/database_mechanics.dart)
#2      refilldb (package:partaykaratay/models/database_mechanics.dart:76:5)
...
...
#14423  refilldb (package:partaykaratay/models/database_mechanics.dart:76:5)
#14424  starterlist (package:partaykaratay/models/database_mechanics.dart:66:32)
#14425  starterlist (package:partaykaratay/models/database_mechanics.dart)
#14426  _GameCatsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:partaykaratay/pages/game_cats.dart:50:27)
```

The file containing the code is database_mechanics.dart. The error is thrown when I try accessing the list - `print(starterlist);`

Answer (score 0):

this is because you're trying to call a method over a List that depends on the function which it returns it in the first place:

```
List<CardFields> starterlist = refilldb("starter"); // here you called the function to get the starterList
```

and inside the `refilldb` method:

```
   List<CardFields> refilldb(String db) {
    /*...*/
    starterlist.clear(); // here you tried to clear that starterList that on the first place depends on the refilldb()
```

so it's like you wrote this:

```
List<CardFields> starterlist = refilldb("starter");
/*...*/
List<CardFields> refilldb(String db) {
  if (db == "starter") {
    refilldb("starter").clear();
/*...*/
```

And this is a recursive function, that doesn't have a condition to get out, so it's like an infinite loop, which causes the `StackOverflow` error.

I know that this answer is very late, but I hope it's helpful.